# Is the disjoint-set data structure implemented natively in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, disjoint-sets, union-find

I searched for a native implementation of the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) in Java. But I didn't find one, only in [external libraries](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-SNAPSHOT/org/jgrapht/alg/util/UnionFind.html).

Did I miss it or does it actually not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was an implementation of the disjoint-set data structure, it would likely be located in the java.util package.  Sets are included, but not disjoint-sets: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html.

The closest I found was the disjoint method in the java.util.collections class: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,java.util.Collection%29